# issue with nnir-search-engine -- Gnus

Tags: gnus

I've a hard time to make Gnus working properly. I got the following error :

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function nnir-search-engine)

Any idea what is wrong? I precise that I've no problem sending some mails, so the SMTP side is fine.

I can provide the full backtrace error if needed. Thanks.

My config:

I've the following in `~/.gnus.el` :

```
(require 'nnir) 
;; I added this require just in case but does not change anything

(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "gmail"
           (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
           (nnimap-server-port 993)
           (nnimap-stream ssl)))
               (nnir-search-engine imap)
               (nnimap-authinfo-file "~/.authinfo")))
```

My `.profile` :

```
export EMAIL="my_mail@gmail.com"
export NAME="Rico"
export SMTPSERVER="smtp.gmail.com"
```

My `.authinfo` :

```
machine SMTP.gmail.com login my_mail@gmail.com port 465 password my_pwd
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah. It seems that you have misplaced the `(nnir-search-engine imap) (nnimap-authinfo-file "~/.authinfo")` part.  That should be inside the parens that start at `'(nnimp "gmail"`.

Correct would be:

```el
(setq gnus-select-method
      '(nnimap "gmail"
               (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
               (nnimap-server-port 993)
               (nnimap-stream ssl)
               (nnir-search-enging imap)
               (nnimap-authinfo-file "~/.authinfo")))
;; -- Two too many ))
```